# jQuery Datatble: Hide row selection information on bottom left of the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am displaying a Jquery Datatable and i need to highlight the row, on row selection. I already figured that out using:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
 select: true
})
```

The problem is, when i select a row, the information "Showing 1 to 10 of 19 entries1 row selected" is displayed on bottom left of the table. I just want to keep the "Showing 1 to 10 of 19 entries". I tried:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
 select: true,
 "bInfo": false
})
```

But, this removes the entire thing. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: can you add a snippet or something ?

Comment: Sure! here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/6u88y9bk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below script: (Code is based on Fiddle)

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table_id').DataTable({
    paging: true,
    select: true
    });

    var table = $('#table_id').DataTable();
    table.select.info( false);

} );
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: Also is there a way to make the first row highlighted by default always? As of now, its highlighted only on clicking.

Answer (score 3):

You were on the right track with using `info:false` but it needs to be inside a `select` object that helps configure the `select`. I also noticed that you have to also specify the `style` option or it doesn't work so I used the default `os` style

more info [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/select)

To answer your comment you can select the first row by using [row().select](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().select()) I have updated my answer to include that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
    paging: true,
    select: {
        style: 'os',
        info: false
    }
  });
  
  // select the first row
  table.row(':eq(0)').select();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.5/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_id" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>XYZ</td>
      <td>ABC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>XYZ</td>
      <td>ABC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>XYZ</td>
      <td>ABC</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Manasa Moodalagiri I updated my answer to include selecting the first row to answer your question in your comment